# Upside down keyboard in android/java

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Is there a way to rotate keyboard 180 degrees so that someone that sees the device upside down can use the keyboard as if it were holding it properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to just flip the keyboard.

However, you can support multiple orientations with android [`android:screenOrientation`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen)

Consider using `fullSensor` for your purpose.

Comment: Is there a way that programmatically I force the screen to get reverse portrait?